# Newton method using polyfit in python + troubleshooting

Tags: python, numpy, tuples

so I'm trying to use the newton method to find roots of a complex function. Here is my code currently:

```
import numpy

xvals = numpy.arange(-5, 5)
def g():
    return numpy.random.random(1) + numpy.random.random(1) *1j
p= numpy.poly1d(numpy.squeeze([g(),g(),g()]))  # test function p
q = numpy.poly1d(numpy.squeeze([g(),g(),g()])) #test function q
f = p/q
pprime = numpy.polyder(p)
qprime = numpy.polyder(q)
print("compare", + numpy.roots(p)) #compare our function to this

def newton(x,tolerance = .000001): #newton method
    x1=1
    x=0
    while (True):
        x1 = numpy.subtract(x, - (1/((pprime/p) - (qprime/q))))
        t = abs(x1 - x)
        if t < tolerance:
            break
    x = x1
    return x
print(newton(1))    
def polyzeros(a): 
    coeff = numpy.polyfit(x,p(x),1) #Returns a vector of coefficients p that minimises the squared error.
    zeros = numpy.polyfit(x,prime(x),1)
    return zeros
print("our answer",+polyzeros(3))
```

There are a couple of different errors occuring

```
16     x=0
     17     while (True):
---> 18         x1 = numpy.diff([x, - (1/((pprime/p) - (qprime/q)))])
     19         t = abs(x1 - x)
     20         if t < tolerance:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'tuple'
```

In this case I tried a couple of different things, such as using numpy.sub or numpy.diff and zip as suggested by others on stackoverflow but to no avail. Any other ideas?

Comment: Your code is riddled by errors, but the thing that gives you the error that you see here is that you are dividing the polynomials as such and not the values in a certain point. You should do `pprime(x)/p(x)` instead of just `pprime/p` et c. In addition, as the code is written now, you `numpy.subtract` a negated expression, which means that in effect you add. But that is still just a start...

Comment: as suggested I fixed those lines, but now my code never breaks out of the while loop.

Comment: As I said, there are plenty of issues with the code. You should probably try with a bit of known data and either set breakpoints (preferably) or print status along the way of execution.